# Ckeditor plugin : how to unwrap text?

Tags: ckeditor, unwrap

I have created a ckeditor plugin that wraps the selected text into a span.
I wonder how can I unwrap the selected when I apply this plugin on a text that has been previously wrapped into the span.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('important', {
    // Register the icons. They must match command names.
    //trick to get a 16*16 icon : http://www.favicomatic.com
    icons: 'important',
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.addCommand('important', {
            // Define the function that will be fired when the command is executed.
            exec: function (editor) {
                var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
                console.log(editor.getSelection()) ;
                var newElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("span");
                newElement.setAttributes({class: 'important'});
                newElement.setText(selected_text);
                editor.insertElement(newElement);
                //how to unwrap the selected text ?


        });

        // Create the toolbar button that executes the above command.
        editor.ui.addButton('important', {
            label: 'Set this as important',
            command: 'important',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, using editor.getSelection().getStartElement(), I can check if the starting element has already been wrapped with the class and remove it if necessary.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('important', {
    //trick to get a 16*16 icon : http://www.favicomatic.com
    icons: 'important',
    init: function (editor) {
        var className = 'important';
        editor.addCommand('important', {
            // Define the function that will be fired when the command is executed.
            exec: function (editor) {
                var editorSelection = editor.getSelection();
                var selected_text = editorSelection.getSelectedText();
                var startElement = editorSelection.getStartElement();

                //if the element has already been wrapped, let's UNwrap it
                if (className === startElement.$.className) {
                    var html = startElement.$.innerHTML;
                    editor.getSelection().getStartElement().remove();
                    editor.insertHtml(html);
                } else {
                    //if the element has NOT already been wrapped, let's wrap it
                    var newElement = new CKEDITOR.dom.element("span");
                    newElement.setAttributes({class: 'important'});
                    newElement.setText(selected_text);
                    editor.insertElement(newElement);
                }
            }
        });

        // Create the toolbar button that executes the above command.
        editor.ui.addButton('important', {
            label: 'Set this as important',
            command: 'important',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```